# Perl: par packer executable with Unicode::GCString, Can't locate object method "new"

Tags: perl, unicode, pp-perl-par-packager

I'm using the [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.036/lib/pp.pm) module to create a Windows executable of a Perl script that uses the `Unicode::GCString` module.

A stripped down version of the script is as follows:

## mwe.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Unicode::GCString;

my $gcs  = Unicode::GCString->new("hello world");
print $gcs->columns();

exit(0);
```

When I run

```
perl mwe.pl
```

the output gives the 'width' of the string:

```
11
```

which is as expected.

I create `mwe.exe` using the command

```
 pp -o mwe.exe mwe.pl
```

and when I run

```
 mwe.exe
```

I receive the error

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Unicode::GCString" at
>   script/mwe.pl line 6

Having reviewed `AppData\Local\Temp\par-xxxxxx\cache-xxxxx\inc\lib`, I believe that `Unicode::GCString` is present, as is `Unicode::LineBreak`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I *think* this will be to do with the dynamic libraries used by the `GCString` module -- I don't think that I'm telling the `PAR::Packer` module to include them, and I think this is the problem. Perhaps a helpful en-route question might be: how do I find the path to the dynamic libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be to use this version of "pp" I call it "ppp.pl"

```
$ENV{PAR_VERBATIM}=1;
system 'pp', @ARGV;
```

Details at https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PAR/lib/PAR/Environment.pod#PAR_VERBATIM

The cause is related to this bug  [Bug #38271 for PAR-Packer: PodStrip does not strip "=encoding utf8" which cause the executable generated by pp failed to exec](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=38271)

Also the boilerplate inside  Unicode::GCString